# Pixel-wise maximum in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working on a Matlab Code and in that i want to find out pixel-wise maximum of red channel, blue channel and green channel of the image. Can anybody tell me how to do this in Matlab?

Comment: So your image is `m*n*3` in size, where the 3 layers are your RGB values. You just take the maximum in the 3rd dimension - `max(M, [], 3)`

Comment: thank you, this solution worked.